# How to add a spinner value to sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

i'm a adding some textview values to sqlite and display it later in a customlistview , now i'm trying to add a spinner value also but it's not working , i'm getting two errors , one in sqlite class , and the other is in the listview class i'll post the errors lines here

Comment: the code if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                SceneInfo scene = new SceneInfo();
                scene.setDate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("id")));
                scene.setDate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date")));
                scene.setStart_time(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("timestart")));
                
 //my attempt to get spinner value//scene.setSection_sv(cursor.getColumnName(cursor.getColumnIndex("section")));

Comment: the other error 

// when i try to display all the info i'm saving // sceneInfos = db1.getAllScene();

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  
Please edit your question for providing more info, do not add comments.